Variation of Polyakov's action (Polchinski)
In Polchinski's book, he states the following equation (which is equation (1.2.27) in the book)
$$\delta S_P = \frac{1}{2\pi\alpha'}\int_{-\infty}^\infty d\tau\int_{0}^\ell d\sigma (-\gamma)^{1/2}\delta X^\mu\nabla^2 X_\mu -  \frac{1}{2\pi\alpha'}\int_{-\infty}^\infty d\tau \left.(-\gamma)^{1/2}\delta X^\mu\partial^\sigma X_\mu\right|_{\sigma=0}^{\sigma=\ell}.\tag{1} \label{1}$$
Starting from the Polyakov action
$$S_P=-\frac{1}{4\pi\alpha'}\int d\tau d\sigma (-\gamma)^{1/2}\gamma^{ab}\partial_a X^\mu\partial_b X_\mu$$
and taking the variation with respect to $X^\mu$ we have
$$\delta S_P=-\frac{1}{4\pi\alpha'}\int d\tau d\sigma (-\gamma)^{1/2}\gamma^{ab}\partial_a (\delta X^\mu)\partial_b X_\mu -\frac{1}{4\pi\alpha'}\int d\tau d\sigma (-\gamma)^{1/2}\gamma^{ab}\partial_aX^\mu\partial_b(\delta X_\mu) \tag{2}\label{2}.$$
By integration by parts in the first summand we obtain
$$-\frac{1}{4\pi\alpha'}\int d\tau d\sigma (-\gamma)^{1/2}\gamma^{ab}\delta(\partial_a X^\mu)\partial_b X_\mu=\frac{1}{4\pi\alpha'}\left[\int d\tau d\sigma (-\gamma)^{1/2}\delta X_\mu\nabla^2 X^\mu-\int_{-\infty}^\infty d\tau\left. (-\gamma)^{1/2}\delta X_\mu \partial^\sigma X^\mu\right|_{\sigma=0}^{\sigma=\ell} - \int_{0}^\ell\left. d\sigma(-\gamma)^{1/2}\delta X_\mu \partial^\tau X^\mu\right|_{\tau=-\infty}^{\tau=\infty}  \right].\tag{3}\label{3}$$
Up to boundary terms this is half the right hand side of \eqref{1}, so I believe both summands in \eqref{2} must be equal, and the boundary terms that correspond to integrals with respect to $\tau$ must vanish.
My questions are:

Is this the correct approach?
If so, how can I prove that both summands in \eqref{2} are equal?
Why does the boundary term \eqref{3} that is an integral with respect to $\tau$ vanish?

A similar question was posted before, but I think my doubt is a bit different.
ADDED:
The main issue for me is that in the second summand in equation \eqref{2} the roles of $X^\mu$ and $X_\mu$ are interchanged. If I make a raising and lowering of indices in the integrand of the second summand I obtain,
$$(-\gamma)^{1/2}\gamma^{ab}\partial_a X^\mu \partial_b(\delta X^\mu)=(-\gamma)^{1/2}\partial^b(\gamma^{\mu\lambda}X_\lambda)\partial_b(\gamma_{\mu\nu}\delta X^\nu),$$
and after applying Leibniz rule, I am unable to rule out extra terms involving the derivatives of $\gamma^{\mu\lambda}$ or $\gamma_{\mu\nu}$. I hope this clarifies the situation.

If $\delta (\partial \phi) = \partial (\delta \phi)$ isn't clear to you, you're going to have trouble with almost every calculation that involves a classical action.

The commutatitivy between $\delta$ and $\partial$ is clear to me, as you can see from equation (3) where I already used it. I'm going to add more details to explain where is the difficulty (to me).

The target space metric does not depend on worldsheet co-ordinates.
